# How to unmarshal an XML document using JAXB and a different, but compatible, context

Tags: xml, replace, namespaces, jaxb

I'm attempting to write a conversion tool that takes a legacy XML document (adhering to oldSchema.xsd) and converts it into a new XML format (adhering to newSchema.xsd).

Perhaps I'm going about this completely wrong, but by first step was to create an intermediate schema that both old and new XML documents validate against.  For example, suppose I have an XML document

```
<Doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="old oldSchema.xsd" xmlns="old">

    <OldElement/>
</Doc>
```

and I want to convert it to

```
<Doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="new newSchema.xsd" xmlns="new">

    <NewElement/>
</Doc>
```

oldSchema.xsd defines Doc as a sequence with a required element called OldElement.  newSchema.xsd defines Doc as a sequence with a required element called NewElement.  My intermediate schema has a sequence with a choice of either OldElement or NewElement.

Obviously, there's more content here that I need to deal with programatically.  Prior to unmarshalling the OldElement XML file, I need to replace the namespace "old" with my intermediate namespace so that I can use a JAXB instance created with my intermediate context.

Is this possible?  I tried implementing my own `XMLStreamReader` that delegates to the `XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader()` for all methods aside from `getNamespaceURI(*)`.  For these, I implemented something such as

```
public String getNamespaceURI() {
    String existingNS = delegate.getNamespaceURI();
    return subs.get(existingNS) == null ? existingNS : subs.get(existingNS)
}
```

where subs would map the namespace "old" to the namespace "new" in my example above.  I repeated this for all `getNamespaceURI(*)` methods in XMLStreamReader.  I then passed an instance of my `NamespaceSubstitutionXMLReader` to `unmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLStreamReader)`.  The unmarshalled object tree had a root node of the correct type, but all of its sub elements were null.  I don't quite understand why this approach didn't work, but then again I'm really not familiar at all with the Unmarshaller implementation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I lead [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), but if all you want to do is transform XML the I would suggest using XSLT and the [javax.xml.transform](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html) APIs.